# processing form with multiple selection options

Tags: python, cgi

I have a cgi script that contains a select box where the end user can submit multiple options or only one option.  This selection tag is named "parameters".  See here for an example....

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

When this form is submitted with multiple options selected the URL looks something like this...

http........mycgiscript.py?parameters=option1value&parameters=option2values

or if the user only selected one option it looks like this...

http........mycgiscript.py?parameters=option3value

My form is declared as...

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

So when the user selects multiple options and submits the form, the data type of form['parameters'] is a list, however, when the user only selects one option and submits, the data type of form['parameters'] is an instance...

**Multiple Options (returned as list):**

```
[MiniFieldStorage('parameters', 'option1value'), MiniFieldStorage('parameters', 'option2value')]
```

**Single Option (returned as instance):**

```
MiniFieldStorage('parameters', 'option3value')
```

My question is....

Since the form['parameters'] can be a list or instance depending on what the user submits; what is the best way to process these two data types ?  The output I want is a list variable containing the optionsXvalues selected on the form.  So far the best I can do is this...

```
if type(form['parameters']) == type([]):
    l = [ x.value for x in form['parameters'] ]
else:
    l = [form['parameters'].value]
```

I've done it this way because simply using form['parameters'].value produces the following exception when the user selects multiple options.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'
```

So is there a better way than my if/else statement based suggestion above?  I was hoping some of you python guru's would be able to suggest a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is use:

form.getlist('parameters')

This provides the value of all the different input types with the same name, namely parameters.

This is what i gathered from http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html in 20.2.2 where they suggest this is the case when you expect there could be multiple items with the same name field.

Hope this helps though i reckon you already found this yourself.